# Persistent execvp on pipe?

Tags: c, operating-system, posix, pipe

I am working on an assignment for my Operating System class (Posix & C), building a mini-shell, and I don't know how to solve the following problem:

My mini-shell has to accept two commands, for example `ls | grep a`. For that I create a pipe of size two and a child. The child closes all that it has to close and opens all that it has to open (standard/pipe's in & out). It then executes "ls," using execvp. I am sure this works well. After that, the parent shuts and opens inputs and outputs (I am sure I do it well), and then executes `grep a`.

Now, the problem is that the process `grep a` never finishes. Same for `tail -1`, e.g.. Yet it does work for `head -1`. I think that happens because `grep` and `tail`, which are executed by the parent, wait for more input, even though the child has finished its operation. `ls | grep a` produces the right output, displayed on the console (The pipe's output is set as default output), but, as I've said, `grep a` does not finish.

So, my question is: how can I inform the parent that the pipe has finished writing, so it can finish the execution of `grep a` for example?

Thank you.

Here's the code:

[fd is the pipe, it is initialized previously in the code. If you can see any incongruous thing, please let me know; I've cleaned the code a bit, and this is only the problematic part, as you can see.]

```
   int fd[2];
   pipe(fd);

   if ((pid = fork()) != -1){ 
     if(pid == 0){         /*Child executing */
        close(fd[0]);
        close(1);
        dup(fd[1]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execvp(argvv[0][0], argvv[0]); /* Here's stored the first instruction */

      } else{             /* Parent executing */
        wait(&status);
        close(fd[1]);
        close(0);
        dup(fd[0]); 
        close(fd[0]);
        execvp(argvv[1][0], argvv[1]); /* Here's stored the second instruction */
       }
   }
```

Comment: grep behaviour is not like "tail -f", you can check it with working shell (like bash). So the problem in something else. Can you post code that run "ls" and "grep"?

Comment: Please include the code from where the `pipe(fd);` call happens.

Comment: The code you've pasted works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the `grep` continues to run after the `ls` has exited, that indicates that you have *not* closed all the pipes that you need to close.

In particular, the write end of the pipe whose read end is attached to the `grep` process is still open in another process.  You will need to show your code to know more.

---

The code you have pasted works correctly (when expanded to a full program, as per the below).  Both subprocesses exit just fine.

This means that you've eliminated the code that has the problem when you created your cut-down version here - perhaps you have another `fork()` between the `pipe()` call and this `fork()`?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
   pid_t pid;
   char *argvv[2][3] = { { "ls", 0, 0}, { "grep", "a", 0 } };
   int status;

   int fd[2];
   pipe(fd);

   if ((pid = fork()) != -1) {
     if(pid == 0){         /*Child executing */
        close(fd[0]);
        close(1);
        dup(fd[1]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execvp(argvv[0][0], argvv[0]); /* Here's stored the first instruction */

      } else{             /* Parent executing */
        wait(&status);
        close(fd[1]);
        close(0);
        dup(fd[0]);
        close(fd[0]);
        execvp(argvv[1][0], argvv[1]); /* Here's stored the second instruction */
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do have another `fork()`. Actually, the parent here is a child.

Thank you very much. I guess I will have to close the pipe of the "real" parent. I'll check ;)

Comment: caf, thank you!

The problem was that I initialized `pipe(fd)` long before creating the first child. That creates a pipe between parent-child, which is unuseful. I only want it for child-grandchild.

Comment: @Sori: Right - every `fork()` duplicates both ends of the pipe if they're still open - so then they need to eventually be closed in both the parent and the child.