# Running pipe commands from child process

Tags: process, pipe, fork

I want to make a shell where the child process runs linux commands(with the help of execvp) such as "ls" etc.The problem is that i also want it to support pipe commands such as "ls /tmp | wc -l" .Τhe program i have for now works for commands like "ls" or "ls -l /tmp" :

Comment: please refer these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801175/classic-c-using-pipes-in-execvp-function-stdin-and-stdout-redirection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129398/persistent-execvp-on-pipe

Comment: Well that really helped!!Thanks a lot